# Spring aop custom annotation gives error in Handler Interceptor class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, interceptor

I have write simple custom annotation in spring aop (spring version 5.1.3.RELEASE).

Then I use it in my handler interceptor class.

### Custom annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Test {}

@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAspect {

    @Before(value = "@annotation(Test)")
    public void beforeInterceptorLog(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("---------test before----------");
    }

    @After(value = "@annotation(Test)")
    public void afterInterceptorLog(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("---------test after----------");
    }
}
```

### Interceptor class.

```
public class CheckAccessInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Test
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

### Spring configuration

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.epic.*" })
public class MainConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(checkAccessInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/v1/**");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CheckAccessInterceptor checkAccessInterceptor() {
        return new CheckAccessInterceptor();
    }
}
```

When i run the application it gives below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method MainConfiguration.checkAccessInterceptor called as bean reference for type [com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.interceptor.CheckAccessInterceptor] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.mainconfiguration.MainConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:577) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1188) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1024) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5085) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5397) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1730) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:485) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:434) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
```

**But when i comment the @Test in interceptor class in works fine.**

Is any one can describe why it happen and how to fix this issue it will be great helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your interceptor also implement the [`afterCompletion(..)` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#afterCompletion-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Exception-)? It looks as if you forgot that. It would mean that you didn't implement the interface correctly and thus the JDK proxy cannot work either. Or did you just give us incomplete code samples here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message : @Bean method MainConfiguration.checkAccessInterceptor called as bean reference for type [com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.interceptor.CheckAccessInterceptor] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117]

I tired by springboot but i haven't found your error.I think below can help you.
change the aop way to CGLIB other than JDK proxy

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.boot" })
public class MainConfiguration {
```

Comment: Because  proxyTargetClass = true is used to take CGLIB other than  JDK  , JDK proxy  generate  class  by implements  interface , JDK proxy generate an class 
like $Proxy..   which can not be casted to CheckAccessInterceptor!  so it throw  Exception .
CGLIB generate class by extending  CheckAccessInterceptor ,maybe class like CheckAccessInterceptorImpl ,but it's  class is like $$EnhancerByCGLIB$$..
the subclass can be cast to CheckAccessInterceptor .  Spring Aop is just take this two way ,hopes it help you!